# Shopify create order admin api not taking email all of a sudden

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

Admin API 2021-10 Orders endpoint is throwing the following error for already existing user

`{\"customer\":[\"Email has already been taken\"]}`

This problem was not there before. Does anyone know if something changed recently API-wise? no documentation regarding the update was found

Comment: API doesn't change once the version has been finalized, like for the 2021-10. What kind of request you're making?

Answer (score 0):

Usually when creating orders, you would want to use a Customer ID for an order when creating it. So you check, via email, does this customer even exist? If it does, you just provide the ID. If you skip that step (remember, customers are a separate aspect of Shopify Orders), you may then run into this issue. Shopify is given an email, tries to create a customer, and the system says STOP RIGHT THERE, this customer already exists, and you never provided an ID.

Sounds weird, but maybe you never encountered this issue because you just never ran into repeat customers? As you know, most orders are one-time and not repeat at a lot of stores.

Not sure this explanation makes total sense, but anyway, the workaround I found was just to establish the customer BEFORE trying to create the order. Either you use an ID for an existing one, or, create a new one.

Comment: Thanks David. But I was able to create orders using repeat user's email id before and it was reflecting in the orders page in shopify admin console. Shopify used to show his old orders as well. All this suddenly started breaking since a couple of days. 

Same payload which I used repeatedly before is not working now!

Comment: Well, the error in the response to your request, so just log that to your console and fix whatever error is there. Remember that the GQL version keeps changing and things change.